# Cannot import name line_search_wolfe2

Tags: python, scipy

I get this error when I try to run a program that uses `SciPy 0.7.2`.

```
from scipy.optimize.linesearch import line_search_wolfe2, line_search_wolfe1
ImportError: cannot import name line_search_wolfe2
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: It's definitely there (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py#L194) - what version of `scipy` are you using?

Comment: I'm using SciPy  0.7.2, it's seems that this version does not contain the library. I use a system where I don' t have admin rights, so I can't install a superior version. Is there a way to use this library and Numpy without installing? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could copy the appropriate code into your own script, but you'd have to make sure you had all of the appropriate dependencies (functions called by that function, etc.).

Comment: You can upgrade Python packages without admin rights, installing them into your home directory, assuming the system has appropriate compilers installed. http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-do-a-user-local-install-of-a-python-package